# jQueryプラグイン「fixedTblHdrLftCol」

Tags: jquery

jQueryプラグイン「fixedTblHdrLftCol」を実装したいのですが、反映されません。
全くの初心者なので、プラグインの方法をいちから教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `反映されません` とありますが実際のコードを転載出来ますか？プラグインの方法をイチから教えるにはSOは不向きです。できるだけ具体的な問題を書いて下さい。そうすればエキスパートの方たちが問題解決の手助けをしてくれると思いますよ。回答をもらえやすい質問の仕方などガイドラインがありますので[SOのツアー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)や [よくある質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help) も一度目を通してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

作者さんのページが[テーブルのヘッダと左列を固定するプラグイン](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nkmrshn/20131220/1387495640)、こちらだと思いますが、こちらであってますでしょうか。こちらに日本語の説明があり、ルールも書かれています。

- jQuery のバージョン 2.1.1 以降
- ヘッダはTHEAD要素内、内容はTBODY要素内

なお、記事の一番下の方に「jQuery CDNとYUI CSS Reset CDNを使っています」とありましたので、[githubのサンプルコード](https://github.com/nkmrshn/fixedTblHdrLftCol)にならってHTMLの `<head>` に記載すると良いでしょうか。

例えば サンプルコードの中にある samples/sample_0_basic.html では、`<head>`の中で次のように書かれていますので、ソースを参考にしてください。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample - Basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.fixedTblHdrLftCol.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('table').fixedTblHdrLftCol({
          scroll: {
            height: '200px',
            width: '550px'
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
```

このように外部サイトのURLを2つ参照しており、jQueryもバージョン2.1.1以降が必須のようです。
さらに、このHTMLの1つ上のディレクトリに、jquery.fixedTblHdrLftCol.jsを配置しましょう。